# Meaning of 漂漂亮亮地参加晚会

Tags: expressions

I saw this sentence on a textbook:

> 漂漂亮亮地参加晚会

Without more context information, what is the translation of that sentence?

I think it has a meaning of "(a girl) dress up beautifully before going to a party", but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. This sentence is equivalent to

```
打扮得漂漂亮亮去参加晚会
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a special point:

If you say this word with a pronunciation piàopiàoliāngliāng (i.e. XX阴平阴平) but not piàopiàoliangliang, it also means "well done", "a neat job", "in style", "chicly",or "be not a procrastinator".

E.g.:

他漂漂亮亮地把事儿给办成了。 -- He did a neat job!

That's *natural + welcome* Chinese:)

Comment: How does this answer the question??

Comment: @JamesJiao I guess that 0xB2CC's answer should be a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's out of context, but:

> *In the case of adjectives composed of two characters (morphemes), generally each of the two characters is reduplicated separately:
>   piàoliang 漂亮 (beautiful) reduplicates as piàopiàoliangliang 漂漂亮亮* (source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication#Chinese)).

And as we know, the function of reduplication is to extend the meaning of the words. So, since the `漂漂亮亮` has no first subject to mention (i.e.: The woman, etc.), `漂漂亮亮` can't stand alone for only `漂亮`, So, the subject here is: 漂亮. And it could means:

1. The beautiful woman dressing nice (before/while) attends the party;
2. 'The beautiful man' dressing nice (before/while) attends the party.

'The beautiful man' just the same with the handsome guys.

Comment: Oh, I thought you can't use 漂亮 with "man".

Comment: @dusan: Of course you can use it.. There is no restriction about the usage of that word. You can use it whenever you see something really good and just saying: `漂亮`..